# passing value from jsp to servlet, what is my mistake?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I've recelty started coding servlets, from what I've read online I'm trying to pass a value from a jsp to my servle,

my.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>my</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="dataprocessingservlet" method="post">
<div id="editor" name = "mytxt">
4
</div>
<button type= "button" style="position: absolute; left: 10%; bottom: 2%;" id="execute" onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Click to execute</button>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
function saveTextAsFile()
{
  window.open('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8085/FirstServlet/mygeco','_top','resizable=yes')
}
</script>
</form></body></html>
```

myservlet.java

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    String text = request.getParameter("mytxt");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(text);

}
```

PS: I've tried passing it by ID also still the null value persists.

here, I am calling my servlet from the jsp page, on an even of onclick.
when I run my jsp page and click the button, a null value is displayed.

What is my mistake how do I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the `saveTextAsFile` function with small update..

```
 function saveTextAsFile()
 {
    var myDivText = document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML;
    window.open('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8085/FirstServlet/mygeco?mytxt=' + myDivText, '_top', 'resizable=yes')
}
```

I have just passed the div content in the query param. let me know if it works.

Comment: can we have a snippet of how is myservlet.java is mapped to the url in your deployment descriptor like web.xml file.

as there you may have to map the url pattern `/FirstServlet` to the fully qualified classpath of myservlet.java

And that should be good to go :)

Comment: Yep, I've already done that. My servlet works fine, I would just like to pass my data in the <div> tag. I'm just trying your solution.

Comment: Hey this works great, but every time I run this my eclipse crashes as soon as I see the output and they the tomcat server says ports are busy? is there some kind of thing I need to do to exit or quit?

Comment: may you have to stop the tomcat server before you start it again or just try restarting the tomcat server through eclipse. you can also check if the port 80 or 8080 is already busy by running the `netstat -a` command. If the answer was helpful, please accept as the correct answer.

Comment: how are you running this code in eclipse. some details please..?? like if you are using some tomcat plugin in the eclipse etc...

Comment: Hey this is not working, its displaying the entire html code.

Comment: as that is very large my eclipse is crashing and work space is unable to load.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47592/discussion-between-suufang-and-doped-dude)

Answer (score 0):

You call the servlet without a query parameter or post value, so how should the value behind "user" be filled? For a test, change the URL to `'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8085/FirstServlet/mygeco?user=HelloWorld`

Comment: No, replace "user" with "mytext" and my answer applies anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're passing nothing to your Servlet, because your're trying to pass a div as i see :

```
<div id="editor" name = "user">
4
</div>
```

but you need to pass an input element, like

```
<input id="user" name="user" type="text"/>
```

Or adding the parameter to your URL like :

```
'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8085/FirstServlet/mygeco?user=MyUserName
```

Answer (score 0):

@suufang: you can pass only `<input> tag` parameters to Servlet but if you want to pass `<div>` data then firstly you will have to get the data of the `<div> tag` and then you will have to pass that data by appending in the URL.

Code is attached below:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>my</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="dataprocessingservlet" method="post">
<div id="editor" name = "mytxt">
4
</div>
<button type= "button" style="position: absolute; left: 10%; bottom: 2%;" id="execute" onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Click to execute</button>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
function saveTextAsFile()
{
  var divData = document.getElementbyId("editor").innerHTML;
  window.open('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8085/FirstServlet/mygeco?mytxt=' + divData,'_top','resizable=yes')
}
</script>
</form></body></html>
```

Try the above solution and see how it goes.